# what is "#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp> "?

Tags: c++, stl

I am new to c++ STL and just encountered with very strange header file

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
```

I google it but unable to find any relevant answer,can any one have clear and short explanation about this actually is?

And i don't think this is an STL library is it write?

Comment: With a simple Google Search: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp

Comment: The first link in Google leads to boost.org. This header is a part of a library called Boost.

Answer (score 2):

[Until version 1.67.0](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/hash/changes.html), that was the header for [the library *Boost.Hash*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/hash.html), part of the [Boost](https://www.boost.org) collection of C++ libraries, in the "Functional" section.

Since then, it's called [*Boost.ContainerHash*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/hash.html), and found at `boost/container_hash/hash.hpp`.